зависает код после запуска браузера selenium
при запуске браузера (Версия Chrome for Testing v129.O.6668.58) останавливается выполнение кода без ошибок, просто открытое окно браузера
версия selenium 3.141.0
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium import webdriver as wd

print("0")

browser = wd.Chrome("C:/Users/amryh/PycharmProjects/pythonProject3/chrome-win64/chrome.exe") #код зависает здесь 

print("1")
driver.get("https://vk.com/")


Какая версия selenium? В актуальной версии 4.25 этот код в принципе не запускается

версия selenium 3.141.0

Ну документация 3 версии намекает, что первым аргументом должен быть путь к chromedriver, а вы вместо него почему-то запихнули путь к браузеру

это путь к chromedriver я его скачал с сайта https://googlechromelabs.github.io/chrome-for-testing/#stable

Нет, Chrome for Testing это просто браузер, это не chromedriver

Спасибо большое

Обновите Selenium до актуальной версии
Например, в 4.23+ для запуска достаточно этого кода, можно и без options
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

options = Options()
options.add_argument('--start-maximized')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
driver.get('ХХХ')

